# Flarum : 403 error for /admin and 404 error for /api

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, nginx-location

I've installed [Flarum](http://flarum.org/) for a forum.

I'm accessing Flarum with this path http://rootUrl/support

I can signup / login add a topic etc...

However when I try to go to the administration panel http://rootUrl/support/admin it gives me a 403 error, and when I try to hit http://rootUrl/support/api it gives me a 404 error. (I haven't used PHP for years)

I'm using nginx 1.8.1 and php5.6.

nginx.conf on the server block:

```
location /support { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /support/index.php?$query_string; 
}

location /support/api { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /support/api.php?$query_string; 
}

location /support/admin { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /support/admin.php?$query_string; 
}

location /flarum {
    deny all;
    return 404;
}

location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
}
```

and on my .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /support

  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  RewriteRule ^vendor/(.*)?$ / [F,L]
  RewriteRule ^storage/(.*)?$ / [F,L]
  RewriteRule ^config.php$ / [F,L]

  RewriteRule ^api(.*)$ api.php [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^admin(.*)$ admin.php [QSA,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule !^assets index.php [QSA,L]

  # MultiViews can mess up our rewriting scheme
  Options -MultiViews

  # Autoindex will list all assets files which is not so good
  Options -Indexes
</IfModule>
```

I also noticed that my .htaccess file is not being read. (removed it nothing changed)

Is anything wrong on my conf ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know Nginx, but AFAIK it has a different rewrite language and no .htaccess support, see https://www.nginx.com/blog/converting-apache-to-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Comment: @OlafDietsche : Thanks, you're right. Let me take a look.

Comment: At scale, `.htaccess` is a very inefficient and stupid way of configuring a web-server; nginx has no support for such bandaids! :-)

Comment: @cnst : yeah I read that on the doc :D I'm not a php developer so I usually use jetty. But now I discovered nginx i'll start using it as à proxy